# How can the Qur'an be eternal?

Tags: quran, hadith, salat, tafseer, islamic-philosophy

According to the *Ahl-Al Sunnah Wa Jam'ah*, the Qur'an is the uncreated, eternal speech of Allah.

> Abu’l-Qaasim al-Laalkaa’i in his book Sharh Usool I‘tiqaad Ahl
> as-Sunnah wa’l-Jamaa‘ah.
>
> He said (2/224):
>
> What we may understand from various reports narrated from the Prophet
> (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) is that the Qur’an **IS ONE OF THE ETERNAL ATTRIBUTES OF ALLAH**..
>
> Then he said (2/227):
>
> There are reports of consensus among the Sahaabah **THAT THE QUR’AN IS NOT CREATED**.
>
> [[Ruling on describing the Qur’an as the eternal word of Allah](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/100585/ruling-on-describing-the-quran-as-the-eternal-word-of-allah), IslamQA]

But since the Qur'an is uncreated and eternal, would this not mean that the Qur'an possesses properties unique to Allah? And are there any resources on this topic? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Since the Qur'an is uncreated and eternal, would this not mean that the Qur'an possesses properties unique to Allah?**

Yes. The whole point of Ahlus-Sunnah's position is to say the Quran is the very speech of Allah which is an attribute of Allah, so obviously the speech of Allah possesses the property of eternality. An attribute of Allah cannot be non-eternal.

Consider, for instance, the knowledge of Allah. Is the knowledge of Allah eternal or created? The same people who claimed the Quran was created also claimed the knowledge of Allah was created. But how can someone say Allah did not always have knowledge?

As for the Quran, it is part of the knowledge of Allah as Allah Himself says:

> And thus We have revealed it as an Arabic legislation. And if you should follow their inclinations after what has come to you of knowledge, you would not have against Allah any ally or any protector. (13:37)

See: [On what basis do Sunni Muslims believe that the Quran is uncreated?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/39074/on-what-basis-do-sunni-muslims-believe-that-the-quran-is-uncreated/75007#75007) for more detailed proofs on the Quran being uncreated.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking about (the discussion of whether or not the Qur'an is a creature) is a philosophical discussion that has caused much theological controversy among Muslims and Muslim philosophers over a period of history. . Theological and ideological differences over the creation or antiquity of the Qur'an had significant political implications for Muslims.

By endorsing and promoting the theory of the creation of the Qur'an, the Abbasid caliphs investigated the views of scholars, judges, and prominent figures, and tortured, exiled, or killed dissidents. This period is called the era of tribulation. Eventually, Mutawakel Abbasi came to the caliphate and prevented discussions and opinions about the creation of the Qur'an and ended the tribulation period.

Shiite imams considered the discussion about the creation of the Qur'an a sedition that should not be entered into. So they advised their followers not to discuss it because it is useless.

Details of these events are found in the history book of Tabari and the history book of Yaghoubi. But for further research on the subject of the creation of the Qur'an, you should read philosophical books on each point of view.
Mu'tazilite books prove the creation of the Qur'an. The book "Sharh's Five Principles" written by Judge Abdul Jabbar Asadabadi and the book "Al-Faeq Fi Usul al-Din" by Mahmud Ibn Muhammad Mollahami Kharazmi have references to this matter.

https://www.porseman.com/article/%D8%AF%D9%8A%D8%AF%DA%AF%D8%A7%D9%87-%D8%B4%D9%8A%D8%B9%D9%87-%D9%88-%D9%85%D8%B9%D8%AA%D8%B2%D9%84%D9%87-%D8%AF%D8%B1%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%87-%D9%85%D8%AE%D9%84%D9%88%D9%82-%D8%A8%D9%88%D8%AF%D9%86-%D9%82%D8%B1%D8%A2%D9%86/21535

Comment: Strange, you are on reputation 1. Last time I checked you had thousands. Is everything alright or is this a different account?